# Magento eWay plugin Function Not Permitted to Terminal

Tags: php, magento, payment-gateway

I'm getting below error with eWay AU Direct plugin in Magento

```
58 Function Not Permitted to Terminal
```

What could this mean???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an error code [returned by your eWay service](https://eway.zendesk.com/entries/478325-what-does-the-58-function-not-permitted-to-terminal-bank-response-code-mean), and not a problem with Magento or your code.